# using zip(*tuple_iterator) without consuming the tuple_iterator at this line

Tags: python, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I have a `tuple_iterator : Iterator[Tuple[A, B]]` and I want to get an `iterator_tuple: Tuple[Iterator[A], Iterator[B]]`
this can in principle be done using `iterator_a, iterator_b = zip(*tuple_iterator)`
However, the `*` within `zip` consumes the whole `tuple_iterator` at the beginning and causes lots of computation.

I would rather have a tuple of iterators, which do not process the data before it is needed. If I consume `iterator_a` first, the code should cache the results of `iterator_b` until I consume `iterator_b`. Using it would be even more clean and less error-prone if it works vice versa, too.

Background info: In between consuming the elements of `iterator_a` I want to start async operations.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't advance "A" without advancing values from "B". This tells me that you have to create a copy (two copies, discarding the original) of your original iterator with [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and take the first and second item from either resulting copy.

`tee` is implemented such that it doesn't consume more memory than it really has to. If you advance both iterators in unison, it should have little overhead.

```py
import itertools
aux_iter_a, aux_iter_b = itertools.tee(tuple_iterator)
# would have to use next(aux_iter_a)[0] and next(aux_iter_b)[1]
iterator_a = (item[0] for item in aux_iter_a)
iterator_b = (item[1] for item in aux_iter_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The library `more_itertools` contains a method which exactly does what I wanted to do:

```
iterator_a, iterator_b = more_itertools.unzip(tuple_iterator)
```

Comment: Good find. And it seems to do what I'm doing for your specific use case https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/b469c17e2bb48d7b9aca11365e112736b8e814f6/more_itertools/more.py#L1824-L1870